# Deriving quadratic regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression, derivation-of-formulae

Hello I was wondering about the math behind quadratic regression. Usually, quadratic regression is done using technology, but if we were to do it manually, how would we develop the regression model?

Comment: Set up the so-called *normal equations*. It is very simple

Comment: Claude Leibovici alwaws proposes the simplest way. Shears. 
2